# play framwork JsRoutes ajax form submit

Tags: ajax, playframework-2.1

im trying to submit a form via  JsRoutes and ajax  and i dont think that im getting to the controller ....

this is my routes

```
POST   /submit    controllers.Application.submit()
```

and this is my jsrouts function:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
JsRoutes.controllers.Application.submit().ajax({
data : $("#contact-form").serialize(),
url: '@{Application.submit()}', 
success : function(data) {
    alert("Succsses");


},
error : function(err) {
    alert("error");

}


});

});
```

this is what im sendig to the server

```
 http://localhost:9000/?name=ajax&lastName=aaa&email=miko5054%40hotmail.com&phone=453534
```

what im doing wrong here ???

Answer (score 1):

The `@{Application.submit()}` code is incorrect. It should be `@{routes.Application.submit()}`.

But if you use the javascript router `JsRoutes.controllers.Application.submit()`, you don't need to specify the url inside the `ajax()` call. You can just remove the `url:...` line and everything should work fine.

Comment: i cant reach   to the controller ....
im using    <form id="contact-form"> </form>
instead of form helpers may by that's the problem...???

Comment: Using direct HTML Form instead of helpers is not a problem.

What do you mean by "I cant reach to the controller" ?

Comment: in debug mode i insert a break point  in the controller method 
 public static Result submit() {
     
     
      
     Date date = new Date();
     
        User filledForm = userForm.bindFromRequest().get();
      
        filledForm.insertDate = date;
        filledForm.save();
  
       
        return ok("@Required annotation kicked in..");
    }

and nothing happen and no data insert to the database

Comment: You should check if you see the POST request in your browser using tools like Firebug or Chrome DeveloperTools, and if you see it, check what the response is.

Comment: it`s not sending a POST its sending a GET 
Request URL:http://localhost:9000/?name=aaa&lastName=aaaa&email=miko5054%40hotmail.com&phone=453534

Comment: That's really strange. Did you remove the `url:...` from your ajax call ? Here is an extract of a code that works for me (see the generated jsRoutes and check if yours is similar) : https://gist.github.com/mguillermin/5619197